# Angular 7 reactive form how to get the text of a selected value instead of the value in drop list form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, formarray

I there a way to get the text of the selected value of a drop down list instead of getting the value, in reactive forms ?

My Script is as the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" formArrayName="test">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="fr" formArrayName="test">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Family Rel. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
              <div [formGroupName]="i">
                <mat-form-field color="warn" >
                    <mat-label>Family Relation</mat-label>
                    <mat-select (selectionChange)="onChange(element, i)" id="family_relation" formControlName="fr" placeholder="Family Relation">                 
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
                        {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
</form>
```

And on change selection `(selectionChange="onChange(element, i)")`, I need to get both selected value and text of it.

```
onChange(data, i)
  {
    let group = (<FormArray>this.formGroup.get('test')).at(i).value;
    let newFr = group['fr'];
    console.log('Value: '+newFr);
  }
```

Where data is the selected row, and `i` is the index of the selected Form Array.

I tried use the old javascript method:

```
<HTMLSelectElement>document.getElementById().text
```

But it gave me an error of:

> [ts] Property 'text' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. [2339]

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
@ViewChild('familyRelation') familyRelation;
```

And:

```
<mat-select #familyRelation (selectionChange)="onChange(element, i)" id="family_relation" formControlName="fr" placeholder="Family Relation">                 
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
                    {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
```

And after consoling:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `[value]="familyRelation.family_relation_type"` ? ...

Comment: I would start with console-logging the whole html-element in your browsers inspection tool as is and then iterate through it until you find the desired property.. By the way - you didn't supply an id to your method ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix that exactly what I have done earlier, and I saw that there is a `text` element but it didn't work

Comment: @trichetriche yes I don't want just that value, I need the text either

Comment: What do you mean by text, this is literally the text you're displaying in your mat-option.

Comment: this.bla.nativeElement.foo.bar normally should work fine in case it's referenced properly  - can you add a screeshot of the expanded property-tree?

Comment: @trichetriche i guess he wants something like : `familyRelation[i].family_relation_type` ...

Comment: @iLuvLogix Yes, give a minute

Comment: @trichetriche Maybe. But in general, if I am not using form array. I just need to get the text of drop down instead of value, that feature does not exist I think ?!

Comment: @alim1990 do you realize that "the text" is a string you provided from an object ? Just match the object and get "the text". + can you show an example of what you have "in general" ?

Comment: @Florian Yeah I know. My whole idea is to simulate the appoach of vanilla javascript, in typescript. Where in js it was just `getElementbyId(bla).text` or `.value`. In typescript form gorup it doesnt seems the same.

Comment: @alim1990 have you considerer using `#familyRelation` with `@ViewChild('familyRelation')` ? It's an 'angular way' to get your html element ref. You can then access to innerHTML

Comment: @Florian better, `<mat-option #options *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="options.innerText">`

Comment: @Florian I will try it now and gets back to you.

Comment: @trichetriche I don't think so as I need them both the value and the text

Comment: @trichetriche I think what he wants he gets "the text" in his method `onChange(element, i)`. But he doesn't want to use the element he is passing as parameter because he wants something more generic that does not rely on the object iself. maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @Florian Thats it.

Comment: @Florian then `<mat-option #options *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" [value]="{ text: options.innerText, value: familyRelation.family_relation_id}">`. But I agree, this is very random and very useless, as the dev is the one deciding which text is displayed in the option.

Comment: @Florian I tried `@ViewChild('familyRelation') familyRelation;` and then console it `console.log(this.familyRelation)` and it returned a mat-select element, I will post it at the end of my question as an edit.

Comment: @alim1990 `this.familyRelation._elementRef.innerText` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 4):

First, get the value from form control. Then get the item related to value by looping through array. Finally get the text from the item

```
onChange(data, i)
  {
    let text = formGroup.get("fr").value;
    let newFr =this.familyRelationArray.find((item) => item.family_relation_id === text)
    if(newFr){
        console.log('text: '+newFr.family_relation_type); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want a generic way to access to your html element. Angular provides an [easy way to do so](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

```
<mat-select #selectFamilyRelation
            (selectionChange)="onChange()" 
            id="family_relation" 
            formControlName="fr" 
            placeholder="Family Relation">                 
  <mat-option *ngFor="let familyRelation of familyRelationArray;" 
              [value]="familyRelation.family_relation_id">
    {{familyRelation.family_relation_type}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Inside your component :

create a class attribute : 
`@ViewChild('selectFamilyRelation') familyRelation;`

then to get the text of your selected option :

```
onChange() {
  const selectedOptionText = this.familyRelation._elementRef.nativeElement.innerText;
  // ...
}
```